# Delete Folders and Files base on the Creation Time

Tags: powershell

I am new in the power shell world, when I try to delete all files older than or equal to two hours, the files with the date of the month before last are not deleted.

```
if (((Get-Volume -DriveLetter C).SizeRemaining / 17Gb) -lt 5) {

    Remove-Item –path c:\testfolder\Dumps –recurse # delete Dumps

    Get-Childitem "c:\testfolder" | Where {$_.CreationTime -lt (get-date).AddHours(-2)} | Remove-Item
}
else {
    Write-Output "False"
}
```

How do I take into account the files and directories of the months before last when deleting? Since I need to delete everything at all that is older than two hours.

Example of files and folders that are currently:

- folder1 time of creation: 29.11.2022 09:48
- file1 time of creation: 29.11.2022 10:11
- file2 time of creation 26.06.2022 12:14

[image]

Comment: Don't use `.ToShortDateString()` for date and time comparisons. PowerShell can compare properties of the type `[DateTime]`. You should use something like `$_.CreationTime -lt $olderThan`

Comment: @Olaf I changed the code, but still files older than two hours are not deleted. I'll attach a screenshot.

Comment: Please do not post images of code or error messages as they are not helpful at all. Instead post the plain text formatted as code IN YOUR QUESTION.

Comment: Please update your question with the exact code you're using.

Comment: OK. Are you sure you show the creation time of the files? By default the Explorer shows the `LastWriteTime`.  ;-)

Comment: @Olaf, these dates are displayed in the explorer. + I just copied the files and folder with the dates I needed to test the code

Comment: OK. What I actually meant is: You may use the wrong filter. You may try `$_.LastWriteTime` instead of `$_.CreationTime` in your `Where-Object` script block. ;-)

Comment: @Olaf, thank you very much for help! how do I mark your answer as a solution?

Comment: It's ok. I'm glad I could help you out. ;-)